# Global ssh key on server

Tags: ssh, server, ssh-keys

I work for a webdevelopment company that also manages the hosting of our customers websites.The hosting is shared and only on 3 servers. The webservers are debian webservers where each customer has his own account to reach his own website files.

Normally I would login to the server as this customer and add my ssh key to an authorized_keys file so that I can simply ssh into the account without having to lookup the password, this works perfectly fine.

The downside is I have to do this for every account over again, is there a way to add it to the server only once so that I can access all the accounts?

I tried putting the authorized_keys file in a .ssh folder in the root of the server but this doesn't seem to provide me access with any account. I have to admit my linux knowledge is limited, so am wondering if this is even possible?

Comment: Please move your question to [su] or [sf]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: @Martin, please note there is a *"This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network"* option when voting to close. (Your comment made Denis [repost the same question](http://superuser.com/questions/951562/global-ssh-key-on-server) on Super User now.) Cheers!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can update your `sshd_config` and add to `AuthorizedKeysFile` also for example some path in `/etc/ssh/authorized_keys` where you can put your master key. This would authorize you with this key to all accounts. But don't forget to leave there also the original one:

```
[...]
AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys /etc/ssh/authorized_keys
[...]
```

Or you can use certificates as described in `ssh-keygen` manual page. This would allow you to audit the access with these keys.

Answer (score -2):

You can consider to use emcSSH tool for your purposes. This is blockchain-based distributed Public Key Infrastructure and group management system.

You can read details and download here: http://emercoin.com/EMCSSH
If needed any assistance, feel free for contact me. I'm author of this system, and can answer your questions.